# How to mock @PrePersist method?

Tags: jpa, mocking, mockito, easymock, jmockit

How do I mock a @PrePersist method, e.g. preInit(), of an entity that I instantiate?

I'm using TestNG. EasyMock is prefered.

```
@Test(enabled = true)
public void testCreateOrder() {
     // Instantiating the new mini order will automatically invoke the pre-persist method, which needs to be mocked/overwritten!
     MiniOrder order = new MiniOrder();
     order.setDate(new Date());
     order.setCustomerId(32423423);
}
```

The MiniOrder.java is an entity that has a pre-persist method. Again, the one I like to mock/overwrite. E.g. `this.id = 1`; Alternatively one could also mock the `IdGenerator.getNewId()` method.

```
@PrePersist
protected void preInit(){
    this.id = IdGenerator.getNewId();
}
```

I don't want the `IdGenertor` class to be called, because it attempts to grab a jndi resource. I just don't understand how to capture this pre-persist method in advance, so that it's not triggered ,respectively replaced by different code, before the object is fully instantiaded.

Comment: So what are you actually trying to test? Do you want to test the funtionality contained within the method marked @PrePersist? (You haven't provided that method in your question, so it'll be hard to help there.) Or are you trying to test that when you perform a persist operation that the @PrePersist method is called?

Comment: @DanTemple Thanks. I rephrased. I want to avoid that the IdGenerator within the pre-persist method is invoked. But, the id, must be set in another way.

Comment: I don't think that you'll be able to mock the call to preInit if it is called during construction of MiniOrder, but you should be able to use [PowerMock](https://code.google.com/p/powermock/) to mock the static method call to `IdGenerator.getNewId()`. Take a look at the [documentation](https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockStatic) to see if this might help you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case, what you really want is to mock the `IdGenerator` dependency, which happens to be called from a `@PrePersist` method.

Using JMockit, the test can be written as follows:

```
@Test
public void createOrder()
{
    new MockUp<IdGenerator>() {
        // change as needed...
        @Mock int getNewId() { return 123; }
    };

    MiniOrder order = new MiniOrder();
    order.setDate(new Date());
    order.setCustomerId(32423423);
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I did :)